# Laravel progressbar on submit

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5, progress-bar, submit

I got a basic form with different inputs, how can I make a progressbar if I submit using Laravel, I have never done this before and could not find a suitable tutorial of doing this.

Comment: Does it submit cause an actual page refresh, or is it completed via an ajax style request?

Comment: its e redirect to another page with an error or success message

Comment: You could use some trickery with something like: http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/ but some progress will happen pre-request, and some when the new page loads

Comment: you ever used that with laravel?

Comment: Not specifically with Laravel

Comment: why not use a simple loader (GIF)

Comment: But I do not know how I should manage that, I never done that before